# Print all linked documents at once from a link

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with a large amount of linked documents.  I need to create a link that says click here to print all.  when you click here, it prints all the linked documents. where can I find instructions?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there is no OOTB method to achieve your needs, I suggest you use VBA.

Click "Alt + F11" Open the VBA console and refer to the code below

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    For i = 1 To 3
            Range("b" & i + 1).Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False
            'ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut
            ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
            Workbooks("sheetname").Activate
    Next
    End Sub
```

In my tests, all hyperlinks were stored in column B, and you needed the appropriate change code.